# Why cant I pull the callback out of the app.get function in node and express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do this in my server.js file:

```
// doesn't work... don't know why.
var findBooks = function (err, books) {
    if (!err) {
        return response.send(books);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

// Get all books
app.get('/api/books', function (request, response, err, books) {
    return BookModel.find( findBooks(err, books));
});
```

and it gives me a 404 error when I run a jQuery xhr in the console, and the same error when I request the page in the browser. It works if I put the callback in the usual place, moving the `findBooks` function into the `BookModel.find` function where it's called and deleting the last two arguments of `app.get`. I'm working though Chapter 5 of Addy Osmani's Backbone.js Applications book to give you some context. Why doesn't this work? Is doing this a good thing, or am I trying something that isn't recommended?

Comment: Can you please put your `BookModel` declaration too? Because Backbone.Model does not provide a `find` function but Backbone.Collection do. There is another problem here, despite the context problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `findBooks` tries to access `response`, but `response` is not in scope at that point.
2. You're calling `findBooks` with `err` and `books` and passing the return value to `BookModel.find`, when you probably want to pass the function for `find` to call.

Let's first solve the second problem. Rather than calling the function, just pass it:

```
return BookModel.find(findBooks);
```

That was easy. Now, to solve the first problem, we'll need to add an extra argument to `findBooks`. I'll assume you put it at the start for reasons I'll detail later. Then we can change the usage to look like this:

```
return BookModel.find(function (err, books) {
    return findBooks(response, err, books);
});
```

It turns out, though, that there's a more concise way to do that, using `bind`. `bind` is best known for its use in binding the value of `this`, but it can also be used to bind arguments:

```
return BookModel.find(findBooks.bind(null, response));
```

All together, we get:

```
function findBooks (response, err, books) {
    if (!err) {
        return response.send(books);
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

// Get all books
app.get('/api/books', function (request, response) {
    return BookModel.find( findBooks.bind(null, response) );
});
```

Comment: @DaFunix: I was assuming that this was server-side code, where Backbone is not being used. I don't know for sure what *is* being used, but the `err` of `findBooks` strongly indicates `find` takes a callback and does its work asynchronously, so I wrote my answer with that in mind.

Comment: @DaFunix Your downvote and comment are not related to the question at hand. The question is about why the callback isn't working properly, and that is because of variable scope, as described in this answer.

Comment: Backbone can be used browser-side or server-side. Moreover, in his question : "I'm working though Chapter 5 of Addy Osmani's Backbone.js Applications book".
So yes, he is using Backbone server-side.
EDIT: This is totally part of the question.
This is never going to work properly as res.send will be called multiple times (and gives the well-known error : "Headers already sent".)

Comment: @DaFunix It appears that his code was working before he refactored the callback outside of context. From the question: "It works if I put the callback in the usual place, moving the findBooks function into the BookModel.find function where it's called and deleting the last two arguments of app.get."

Comment: @DaFunix: I'm aware that Backbone *can* be used on the server side, but I was assuming it *wasn't*. I did see that they referenced a book on it, but given 1) how seldom I imagine Backbone is used on the server side; 2) the question is not tagged [tag:backbone]; and 3) how I can't imagine that `err` would be used as a parameter name to a Backbone iterator function, I assumed that it was merely some server-side code to support a Backbone application.

Comment: Yes, i do understand why you did the mistake and that's totally legit. Anyway, if his code was "not crashing", it's a combination of circumstances. I will remove my downvote as soon as you will edit your post.

Comment: Have not tried this yet, but I can see from the answer given and the stellar explanation that it will get me to on the right track to finding a working solution. This is node and express.js code, so yes it is server side. I referenced the book just in case someone had the book and could look at my question in a broader context.

Comment: Oh... I also find it ironic that you aren't sure if this is client or server side code. I mentioned that it's in my server.js file, and tagged the post with server side tags. Apparently that leaves the issue clear as mud. :)